# how to make mobile app using html

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile

I am able to develop android native applications using android SDK, but now I'd like to learn how to develop mobile applications using HTML5. Which tool is used to develop these mobile application in HTML5? Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for apache cordova (phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

You can make html5 apps/hybrid apps using phonegap/Jquery mobile.

See details below:
http://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app/
http://phonegap.com/

https://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of hybrid platform frameworks are available like phonegap, ionic ect. These are make use of html,css,java script and angular js. So make a search in these category and start creating your on applications.

If you want more details refer this link : http://www.sitepoint.com/top-7-hybrid-mobile-app-frameworks/

Comment: which type facebook app

Comment: and how to maintain data base